# check if values of a column are in values of another numpy array column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
dt = pd.DataFrame({'id' : ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'],
                   'col_a': [1,2,3,1,2],
                   'col_b': [2,2,[2,3],4,[2,3]]})
```

I would like to create a column which will assess if values `col_a` are in `col_b`.

The output dataframe should look like this:

```
dt = pd.DataFrame({'id' : ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'],
                   'col_a': [1,2,3,1,2],
                   'col_b': [2,2,[2,3],4,[2,3]],
                   'exists': [0,1,1,0,1]})
```

How could I do that ?

Comment: If data are `'col_b': [2,2,[2,3],4,[20,30]]` then last value is `False` or `True` ? You need test by rows?

Comment: it should be false then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solutions if need test values per rows (it means not each value of column `cola_a` by all values of `col_b`):

You can use custom function with `if-else` statement:

```
f = lambda x: x['col_a'] in x['col_b'] 
              if isinstance(x['col_b'], list) 
              else x['col_a']== x['col_b']
dt['e'] = dt.apply(f, axis=1).astype(int)
print (dt)
  id  col_a   col_b  exists  e
0  a      1       2       0  0
1  a      2       2       1  1
2  a      3  [2, 3]       1  1
3  b      1       4       0  0
4  b      2  [2, 3]       1  1
```

Or [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) with compare both columns and then test it at least one `True` per index values:

```
dt['e'] = dt.explode('col_b').eval('col_a == col_b').any(level=0).astype(int)
print (dt)
  id  col_a   col_b  exists  e
0  a      1       2       0  0
1  a      2       2       1  1
2  a      3  [2, 3]       1  1
3  b      1       4       0  0
4  b      2  [2, 3]       1  1
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```py
dt["exists"] = dt.col_a.isin(dt.col_b.explode()).astype(int)
```

`explode` the list-containing column and check if `col_a` `isin` it. Lastly cast to `int`.

to get

```
>>> dt
  id  col_a   col_b  exists
0  a      1       2       0
1  a      2       2       1
2  a      3  [2, 3]       1
3  b      1       4       0
4  b      2  [2, 3]       1
```

If row-by-row comparison is required, you can use:

```py
dt["exists"] = dt.col_a.eq(dt.col_b.explode()).groupby(level=0).any().astype(int)
```

which checks `eq`uality by row and if `any` of the (grouped) `explode`d values gives `True`, we say it `exists`.

Comment: Solution is wrong if OP need test per rows, working only for sample data, try `'col_b': [2,2,[2,3],4,[20,30]],`

Comment: @jezrael thank you, i added a line for strict row inclusion case.